# How can i compare the context of two different paragraph using machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, bots

I am beginner and i am trying to create a bot which can take technical interview, so i need some method to compare the answers of candidate to the actual answer.
comparing on the basis of sentence scoring is not applicable,so any other approach which can help?
you can share any git library relevant to it!!

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the contextual similarity between two pieces of text. You can use the following techniques:

```
Jaccard Similarity ☹☹☹
Different embeddings+ K-means ☹☹
Different embeddings+ Cosine Similarity ☹
Word2Vec + Smooth Inverse Frequency + Cosine Similarity 
Different embeddings+LSI + Cosine Similarity ☹
Different embeddings+ LDA + Jensen-Shannon distance 
Different embeddings+ Word Mover Distance 
Different embeddings+ Variational Auto Encoder (VAE)  
Different embeddings+ Universal sentence encoder 
Different embeddings+ Siamese Manhattan LSTM 
BERT embeddings + Cosine Similarity ❤
Knowledge-based Measures ❤
```